# Finds a position to break a string that is not part of a <br>

Tags: javascript

I have a 'read more' angular directive copied from:
https://github.com/doukasd/AngularJS-Components/blob/master/dd-text-collapse/dd-text-collapse.js

Some of my text can already have `<br>` tags in it (I ONLY allow just `<br>`) so I just needed to handle that...below is only the extra code I wrote for this purpose.

Does it seems long for something seemingly trivial?

```
    //---All this to not break upon <br> --
    if (text.includes('<br>')) {
        var charAtMaxLength = text.charAt(maxLength).toLowerCase();
        //console.log(charAtMaxLength);
        switch (charAtMaxLength) {
            case '<':
                if (text.charAt(maxLength + 3).toLowerCase() === '>') {
                    //console.log('Decrease maxLength by 1');
                    maxLength -= 1;
                }
                break;
            case 'b':
                if (text.charAt(maxLength - 1).toLowerCase() === '<') {
                    //console.log('Decrease maxLength by 2');
                    maxLength -= 2;
                }
                break;
            case 'r':
                if (text.charAt(maxLength - 2).toLowerCase() === '<') {
                    //console.log('Decrease maxLength by 3');
                    maxLength -= 3;
                }
                break;
            case '>':
                if (text.charAt(maxLength - 3).toLowerCase() === '<') {
                    //console.log('Increase maxLength by 1');
                    maxLength += 1;
                }
                break;
            default:
                //Do nothing.
                break;
        }
        //console.log(charAtMaxLength);
    }
    //--------------------------------------
```

Comment: No need of `toLowerCase` on special characters.

Comment: Seems like Assembly language where you have to manually handle all kind of string ops.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to check if the letter that you have matched is part of a `<br>`.
But you're doing a strange check. That has bugs.

Lets say we test:

> ```
> a<bc>d<br>
> ```

we say that `maxLength` is `1`.
You'll not break the `<bc>`.
For a dry test of this:

```
text.includes('<br>') # true
text.charAt(maxLength).toLowerCase() # '<'
switch ('<')
case '<':
text.charAt(maxLength + 3).toLowerCase() === '>' # true
maxLength -= 1 # maxLength = 0
```

Instead you can use, `indexOf`, `slice` and `length` to check if the text is not allowed.
This allows for you to easily change what you want to remove, and to expand on it.
Whilst being much smaller than what you have.

1. Get the, lowercase, `charAt`.
2. Find the `indexof` it in the remove string.
3. Set the start as `maxLength` minus the `index`.
4. Check if the `index` is in the remove string, and check if the `slice` of text from start to start plus the remove strings `length` is the remove string.
5. If it is change the `maxLength` to `start - 1`.

Or in JavaScript:

```
var text = 'a<br>d<br>';
var remove = '<br>';
var maxLength = 4;

var char = text.charAt(maxLength).toLowerCase();
var index = remove.indexOf(char);
var start = maxLength - index;
if (index != -1 && text.slice(start, start + remove.length).toLowerCase() == remove) {
    maxLength = start - 1;
}
```

Comment: Awesome, I kind of knew mine was rubbish and you sorted it for me, Thanks.  I tested via fiddle https://jsfiddle.net/zaxjvrr3/3/

Comment: After more testing I just removed the -1 on 2nd to last line: https://jsfiddle.net/zaxjvrr3/4/

Answer (score 0):

Use a regexp:

- strip `<`, `<b` at the cut
- add back `>` for `<br`

```
function cut(text, maxLength) {
    return text.substr(0, maxLength)
               .replace(/<b?$/i, '')
               .replace(/<br$/i, '<br>');
}
```